# Usage of FileInfo and DirectoryInfo classes on Mono - Linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux, mono

I have 2 small questions here.

1. I am working on one of the .net application that we want to execute
   on Linux too. My obvious choice is to run it using Mono. This
   application is using extensive File and Directory enumeration and
   gathering file and directory information. When I went through [Mono
   Documentation](http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=P%3AMono.Unix.UnixDirectoryInfo.Name), I found that Mono has designed UnixDirectoryInfo,
   UnixFileInfo classes separately. My query is, does this means that
   they are not supporting FileInfo and DirectoryInfo which are their
   in BCL (System.IO name space).
2. I know that the traditional File and Directory enumeration in .NET
   is slow, I have gone through many articles where people recommend
   using PInvoke calls with FindFirst(...) FindNext(...) on Windows. I
   am fully aware that this will not work on Linux. Has anyone worked
   in this area specially on Mono Linux to test the File/Dir
   enumeration performace.

Thanks,
Omky

Comment: Take a look here ;) https://github.com/mosa/Mono-Class-Libraries/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileInfo.cs

Comment: They do support FileInfo and DirectoryInfo at least in 3.6 (I'm sure it's been there for a long time though). It could internally redirect to the UnixFile/DirInfo though. I'm not sure. As for the performance, I would imagine it would run very fast in Linux/Unix since their file system is inherently faster (subject to debate and not scientifically accurate since I don't have the data to support it) but to find out, write a test case and run it in your distro to test your usecase.I don't have any performance data but when I used it, it wasn't noticeably slow. If anything, it looked to be faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically it should be faster on Linux machines as the file system enumeration is generally faster than Windows.

but We want to assess Mono BCL against custom Mono.Posix, I checked underlying implementation of both assemblies and while both would call system functions at the end, the route is different as the former use Mono runtime abstractions but the latter use direct p/invoke, so I wrote a simple code to assess performance differences for Directory and File enumeration and here it is:

```
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Assess ("/opt",5, false);
        Console.WriteLine ("**********************");
        Assess ("/opt",5, true);
    }

    public static void Assess (string root,int iteration, bool net=true)
    {
        var watch = new Stopwatch ();
        var fCount = 0;
        var dCount = 0;

        watch.Start ();
        for (var i=0; i<iteration; i++) {
            if (net) {
                Console.WriteLine ("assessing .Net Bcl");
                var dirInfo = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo (root);
                AssessNet (dirInfo, ref fCount, ref dCount);
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine ("assessing Mono Posix");
                var unixDirInfo = new Mono.Unix.UnixDirectoryInfo (root);
                AssessMono (unixDirInfo, ref fCount, ref dCount);
            }
        }
        watch.Stop ();
        Console.WriteLine ("crawl time: {0} ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.WriteLine ("files count: {0}, directory count: {1}", fCount, dCount);
    }

    public static void AssessNet (System.IO.DirectoryInfo root, ref int fCount, ref int dCount)
    {
        var files = root.GetFiles ();
        var dirs = root.GetDirectories ();

        foreach (var f in files) {
            fCount++;
        }

        foreach (var d in dirs) {
            dCount++;
            AssessNet (d, ref fCount, ref dCount);
        }
    }

    public static void AssessMono (Mono.Unix.UnixDirectoryInfo root,ref int fCount,ref int dCount)
    {
        var entries = root.GetFileSystemEntries ();

        foreach (var e in entries) {
            if (e.IsDirectory) {
                dCount++;
                AssessMono (e as Mono.Unix.UnixDirectoryInfo,ref fCount,ref dCount);
            } else {
                fCount++;`enter code here`
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tested with Mono 3.2.8  on Ubuntu 14.04.1 64-bit

Here is the result:

**assessing Mono Posix**

crawl time: 469 ms,
files count: 16020, directory count: 2965

---

**assessing .Net Bcl**

crawl time: 705 ms,
files count: 16020, directory count: 2965

based on my experiment there is a performance difference, so based on your requirement, and considering subtle differences between the two API , it may not be such a bad idea to write a thin wrapper to achieve best results on both Operating Systems
(we can use direct Win32 calls on windows as default implementation of File and Directory IO in .Net is slow too).

Comment: Your answer Helped me a lot for deciding a strategy of implementation....many thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

> I found that Mono has designed UnixDirectoryInfo, UnixFileInfo classes
>   separately. My query is, does this means that they are not supporting
>   FileInfo and DirectoryInfo which are their in BCL (System.IO name
>   space).

There **is support** for the `System.IO.FileInfo` & `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` along with the `Mono.Unix.FileInfo` & `Mono.Unix.DirectoryInfo`. Hence to write portable code, we should use `System.IO` facility. The below sample code has been written which uses `System.IO`

## VersionInfo

```
MonoDevelop 3.1.0
Installation UUID: e5e69249-f5d5-40a6-9424-2ecbdf6c71c7
Runtime:
    Mono 2.10.8.1 (Debian 2.10.8.1-1ubuntu2.2) (64-bit)
    GTK 2.24.10
    GTK# (2.12.0.0)
Build information:
    Git revision: unknown
    Build date: 2012-08-15 10:45:07+0000
Operating System:
    Linux
    Linux mantosh-Inspiron-3521 3.2.0-67-generic #101-Ubuntu S
    MP Tue Jul 15 17:46:11 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

## SampleProgram

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Test
{
    class DirInformation
    {
        static public void DoSomething ()
        {
            string name = null;
            name = "/home/mantosh/";
            DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo (name);
            bool dirExists = info.Exists;
            Console.WriteLine(dirExists);
        }

        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            DoSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

> I am fully aware that this will not work on Linux. Has anyone worked
>   in this area specially on Mono Linux to test the File/Dir enumeration
>   performance.

I think instead of guessing, we should write the sample application and verify the performance. I have not done any performance analysis on on MONO but typically any framework/library code would be bit slower compared to directly system calls. But with
framework/library, we get better error handling and of course the more portable code.

My advice would be if your intention is to write a portable application, you should stick with framework(in this case Mono).